# Upgrade to 4.5.0 fails

Tags: drupal, upgrade, javascript, 4.5

I'm trying to move from 4.4.19 -> 4.6 (Old LTS to new LTS).  Having trouble and not sure where to look next.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

When I go to the update page /civicrm/upgrade?reset=1 the page loads fine, but then when I hit the button to upgrade, I get a javascript error: Javascript error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token runner:1" .

I experimented with trying to make smaller upgrades, and I **can** successfully upgrade from 4.4.19 -> 4.4.20, but 4.4.20 -> 4.5.0 gives that same javascript error. (I also tried 4.5.1 with same result.)

There is nothing in the drupal log.

There are no new entries in /civicrm/ConfigAndLog

Things I've tried based on what I've read here and elsewhere:
-Upgraded to most recent version of chrome
-Deleted contents of civicrm_extensions directory
-Disabled all civicrm drupal modules (except CiviCRM Contact Reference Field which wont allow me to disable it because it's in use for a field)
-Deleted contents of custom php and custom templates directories
-Turned on debugging

Comment: i guess the issue is resolved?